# using Python eval() Method to execute a string format function and return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

```
x = """
def test_add(a, b):
    add = a + b
    return add

test_add(10, 6)
"""
print(eval(x))
```

The above code produces following error:

```
File "<string>", line 2
    def test_add(a, b):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can i fix this error ?
Note : In this example, `16` should be printed to the console.

Comment: I believe `eval` only evaluates expressions.

Comment: Eval expects an expression an returns its value. You need exec and put the print statement inside the string because exec return None.

Answer (score -2):

The eval() method can returns the result evaluated from the expression.

```
a = 10
b = 6
print(eval("a+b"))
```

Comment: Ok, and? How does that answer the question? You didn't explain why the code in the question doesn't work or how to fix it...